# R- One way anova extracting p_value

Tags: r, anova, p-value, broom

I'm trying to do a one-way anova on several row of a dataset and extract the p_value to use it afterwards.

Here's what i've done:

```
anova <- function(x) {summary(aov(x ~ bt.factor))[[1]]["Pr(>F)"]}
anv.pval <- apply(golubALL, 1, anova)
```

With this formula i'm able to extract the pvalue but it comes with other elements:

```
$`1414_at`
            Pr(>F)
bt.factor   0.7871
Residuals
```

What I would like to have as a result is only this in a list. How could I extract it ?

Comment: Add [[1]] between ] } and see the output. Is all about the positions in summary output so will be usefull to have data so we can replicate the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html).  With `tidy()`, you can extract only the `p.value` field:

```
require(broom)
a <- aov(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

tidy(a)
#        term df    sumsq     meansq statistic      p.value
# 1        wt  1 847.7252 847.725250  91.37533 1.293959e-10
# 2 Residuals 30 278.3219   9.277398        NA           NA

tidy(a)$p.value
# [1] 1.293959e-10           NA
```