# Fail to extra p-value from aov using tidy

Tags: r, anova, broom

I am using this
[R- One way anova extracting p_value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441210/r-one-way-anova-extracting-p-value)
but failed...

So here is an over my code:

```
anova_sink<-c("a","b","c","d")
aov_result<-vector()
p_result<-vector()
for(i in 1:(length(anova_sink))){
  aov_result[i]<-aov(as.formula(paste("value","~",anova_sink[i])),df)
  p_result[i]<-tidy(aov_result[i])$p.value

}
```

This returned error

```
Error: No tidy method recognized for this list.
```

But according to

https://rdrr.io/cran/broom/man/tidy.aov.html

it should be fine.

I don't really know why...

To be honest, at this point, my problem is solved with [Extract p-value from aov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366506/extract-p-value-from-aov), however, I still want to know why the other method is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a double bracket (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)) to access the element of the list, so it should be:

```
tidy(aov_result[[i]])
```

and

```
aov_result[[i]]
```

So below is an example dataset:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=5))
colnames(df) = c("a","b","c","d","value")
```

And we run your corrected code, note we get the first p.value from `tidy()`  out:

```
anova_sink<-c("a","b","c","d")
aov_result<-vector("list",length(anova_sink))
p_result<-vector()
for(i in 1:(length(anova_sink))){
  aov_result[[i]]<-aov(as.formula(paste("value","~",anova_sink[i])),df)
  p_result[i]<-tidy(aov_result[[i]])$p.value[1]

}

p_result
[1] 0.95105366 0.00341931 0.48760857 0.95084692
```